# Is there a way to add private keys in ReadTheDoc?

Tags: read-the-docs

I want to host my documentation on [ReadTheDoc](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) because.... it's great.

Problem my repository use Google Earth Engine as a dependancy. This lib require a manual authentification or an authentification through a private key.

Is it possible to use private key in ReadTheDoc ? (in Json or string format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the RTD administration panel of your repository go to "Environment Variables". there you will be able to add as many env keys as you fancy.

> note that once set, the key will not be publicly displayed to you or any other maintainer for security reasons obviously

**Troubleshooting**

As referenced in this [issue](https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org/issues/7901#issuecomment-776906518) if your key is bigger than 2048 characters, it will not be managed by RDT. In this case encrypt your key in a file inside your repository and add the decoding key as an environment variable in RDT.